# including CSS file in Vue project

Tags: css, vue.js, import, include, styles

I am new to Vue and I had a problem understanding how thinks works in Vue, One of the problems was including my own custom CSS file in a project.

I have created file **style.css** in **src** folder and the code in **index.html** didn't worked for me:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

I had to import styles in **main.js** file and copied the whole path

`'/home/timotej/Desktop/TestProjekt/projekt/src/style.css'`

so the whole **main.js** file looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import style from '/home/timotej/Desktop/TestProjekt/projekt/src/style.css'  // styles ..

Vue.use(style)  // styles ..

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

now it should work !